# Make a Publisher from a callback

Tags: swift, combine

I would like to wrap a simple callback so that it would be able to be used as a Combine `Publisher`. Specifically the [NSPersistentContainer.loadPersistentStore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer/1640568-loadpersistentstores) callback so I can publish when the container is ready to go.

```swift
func createPersistentContainer(name: String) -> AnyPublisher<NSPersistentContainer, Error> {
  // What goes here?
  // Happy path: send output NSPersistentContainer; send completion.
  // Not happy path: send failure Error; send completion.
}
```

For instance, what would the internals of a function, `createPersistentContainer` given above, look like to enable me to do something like this in my `AppDelegate`.

```swift
final class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  let container = createPersistentContainer(name: "DeadlyBattery")
    .assertNoFailure()
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()

  // ...

}
```

Mostly this boils down to, how do you wrap a callback in a `Publisher`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that Combine's [`Future`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/future) is the correct tool for the job.

```swift
func createPersistentContainer(name: String) -> AnyPublisher<NSPersistentContainer, Error> {
  let future = Future<NSPersistentContainer, Error> { promise in
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: name)
    container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
      if let error = error {
        promise(.failure(error))
      } else {
        promise(.success(container))
      }
    }
  }
  return AnyPublisher(future)
}
```

Comment: The problem of using only the Future, though, is that it is eager, which means that it starts executing its promise closure at the moment of creation, not when it is subscribed to. The answer to that challenge is to [wrap it in the Deferred publisher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60622257/777302).

Comment: How about a Connectable Publisher?

Answer (score 16):

As one of the previous posters @Ryan [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56875265/777302), the solution is to use the `Future` publisher.

The problem of using only the `Future`, though, is that it is eager, which means that it starts executing its promise closure at the moment of creation, not when it is subscribed to. The answer to that challenge is to wrap it in the `Deferred` publisher:

```swift
func createPersistentContainer(name: String) -> AnyPublisher<NSPersistentContainer, Error> {
    return Deferred {
        Future<NSPersistentContainer, Error> { promise in
            let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: name)
            container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
                if let error = error {
                    promise(.failure(error))
                } else {
                    promise(.success(container))
                }
            }
        }
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`NSPersistentContainer` is just a convenience wrapper around a core data stack, you would be better off subscribing at the source:

`NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChange)`

Comment: This is an answer to some question just not this one. This does not address the wrapping the result in a `Publisher`.

Comment: Well wrapping a wrapper is a very bad idea so I gave you an answer that puts you on the right track. StoresDidChange is the correct notification for "when the container is ready to go" and it is already a publisher via notification center.

Comment: The idea that `loadPersistentStores(completionHandler:)` is a bad idea for telling when the core data stack is fully initialized and is ready for use runs counter to the official documentation.

Comment: loadPersistentStores just loops the current storeDescriptions and adds a persistent store for each. If you want to load a new store you need to set a new store descriptions array, if you call load again without changing the descriptions it fails with stores already loaded. This is quite an ugly wrapper and not really suitable for Combine. The best way to know when a persistent store is really ready to go is the NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChange which I mentioned.