# Convert function with completionHandler to Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I'm trying to change my function from using a completion handler to a function that uses combine, but I'm getting an error message.

1. with completionHandler:

   ```
    typealias AuthorizationCompletion = (UNAuthorizationStatus) -> ()

    func reloadAuthorizationStatus(completion: @escaping AuthorizationCompletion) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let notificationStatus = settings.authorizationStatus
            completion(notificationStatus)
        }
    }
   ```
2. Using Combine:

   ```
    func reloadAuthorizationStatus() -> AnyPublisher<UNAuthorizationStatus, Error>  {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
        Just(settings)
            .tryMap({$0.authorizationStatus})
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
   ```

But getting the error Cannot convert return expression of type 'Void' to return type 'AnyPublisher<UNAuthorizationStatus, Error>'

From the moment I add the return type to the function, the settings let will change from type UNNotificationSettings to error type

What am I missing here ?

Comment: getNotificationSettings does not return AnyPublisher

Comment: You'll likely want to use `Future`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56874689/make-a-publisher-from-a-callback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Future` is the publisher you need

```
func reloadAuthorizationStatus() -> AnyPublisher<UNAuthorizationStatus, Never>  {
    Future<UNAuthorizationStatus, Never> { promise in
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            .getNotificationSettings { settings in
            promise(.success(settings.authorizationStatus))
        }
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: could you please post a whole example - not only publisher creating?